# '\n' in textContent giving wrong offsetHeight when binary search is applied to find the max characters after which the text needs to be truncated

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
export function getMaxCharLength(target, maxHeight, { showMoreLabel = '' }: $TSFixMe = {}) {
  const charHtml = `<span class="js-shave-char">&hellip;${showMoreLabel}</span>`;

  // If already short enough, we're done
  if (target.offsetHeight < maxHeight) return Infinity;

  // Clone the target element
  const clonedEl = target.cloneNode(true);

  // Create a hidden container outside viewport and insert the cloned target element in it
  const clonedElContainer = document.createElement('div');
  clonedElContainer.setAttribute(
    'style',
    `position: absolute; left: -10000px; zIndex: -10000; visibility: hidden; width: ${target.offsetWidth}px`
  );
  clonedElContainer.appendChild(clonedEl);

  // Append the hidden container to DOM
  document.body.appendChild(clonedElContainer);

  const fullText = clonedEl.textContent;
  // Binary search for number of words which can fit in allotted height
  let max = fullText.length - 1;
  let min = 0;
  let pivot;
  while (min < max) {
    pivot = (min + max + 1) >> 1; //eslint-disable-line no-bitwise
    clonedEl.textContent = fullText.slice(0, pivot);
    clonedEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', charHtml);
    if (clonedEl.offsetHeight > maxHeight) max = pivot - 1;
    else min = pivot;
  }

  // Remove the hidden container from DOM
  clonedElContainer.remove();

  return fullText.slice(0, max).length;
}
```

This function implements a binary search to implement the basic showMore/showLess functionality.
Using this function, we get the max number of characters that needs to be shown on UI according to the passed maxHeight.(followed by '...' and showMore text).
It works fine with the normal content. For example, if my content is = "rat, bat, cat, chat, fat, mat, pat, jat, iut, uio, gtr, bat, rat, yrt, rad, ugat, asd, disa, sajdghu" and maxHeight is 30, and width of the target is small (150), text on UI is "rat, bat, cat, chat, fat, mat, pat, jat, iut, uio, gtr, bat, rat, yrt, rad, ugat, asd ...Show More"

Whenever the content of the target contains '\n' (linebreak), this function results in max = 0, hence slicing the entire text.
Also, upon debugging, I found that offsetHeight of clonedEl at every loop comes wrong. But this happens only when the values are separated with '\n'. It works perfectly well when delimiter is semi-colon or comma.

getMaxCharLength code inspiration:
"https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/shave/blob/master/src/shave.js"

NOTE: CSS maxHeight and ellipsis property not to be used here.

Comment: Could you simply filter out linebreaks? Depending on how this is being displayed, you may want to ignore them anyway.

Comment: I want to show line breaks too on the UI.

Comment: Also, I am unable to find the reason why '\n' is creating a problem. Let me know if you find anything wrong here. Thanks for ur help in advance :)

Comment: One more thing, aim of this function is to get characters based on height, so '\n' should be considered in the textContent so as to get he correct height.